# Admob ads not working with phone gap in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, admob

I am trying to create admob ads in my phonegap application.

so I followed this 2 links but I could not understand why it is not working.

[ios phonegap plugins](https://github.com/acyl/phonegap-plugins-1/tree/master/iOS/AdMobPlugin)

[setup Admob in iOS project](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios)

it is not giving me any error. it just not don't showing this error.

```
document.ready(function(){
window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView(
     {
       'publisherId': 'INSERT_YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID_HERE',
       'adSize': AdMob.AdSize.BANNER
     },
     successCallback,
     failureCallback
 );


logCreateBannerSuccess();
 window.plugins.AdMob.requestAd(
     {
       'isTesting': false,
       'extras': {
         'color_bg': 'AAAAFF',
         'color_bg_top': 'FFFFFF',
         'color_border': 'FFFFFF',
         'color_link': '000080',
         'color_text': '808080',
         'color_url': '008000'
       },
     },
     successCallback,
     failureCallback
 );
});
```

I dont understand where i am going wrong.

please help me out.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is no ad to show. Look in your logs to confirm this.
You could also request test ads to confirm that it is working.

How to ask for test ads:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

// Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for
// the simulator as well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"MY_SIMULATOR_IDENTIFIER",
                           @"MY_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER",
                           nil];
```

For more details see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios

Comment: can you please explain? how?

Comment: Thank you might be my key word for google was incorrect,anyway let me try this.